# RMSE derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to calculate the RMSE derivatives? Should I use chain rule and threat the MSE as the nested function? Such as:

$RMSE = \sqrt{MSE}$

So the derivative is (applying chain rule):

$RMSE' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{MSE}} \cdot MSE'$

Moving forward:

$RMSE' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}\sum(h(x) - y)^2}}\cdot\frac{2}{m}\sum(h(x) - y) = \frac{\sum(h(x) - y)}{m\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}\sum(h(x) - y)^2}}$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{u(x)}$ is $1/[2 \sqrt{u(x)}]\cdot u'(x).$ You omitted the squareroot in denominator of result.

Comment: I modified as you suggested but still I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Looks good, but you can simplify the denominator further to $\sqrt{m\sum(h(x) - y)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes its correct, the chain rule works as follows.

If F(x) = f(g(x))
Then F'(x) = f'(g(x)) * g'(x)

This is the derivative of the outer function with respect to the inner function multiplied by the derivative of the inner function with respect to x.

The chain rule is used to calculate the gradient of a function inside another function.

This gradient represents how the inner function is affecting the result produced by the outer function.

It specifically denotes how the output changes in response to that variable or function.

[Chain Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLCg4.png)

The derivative of the square root f(x)=sqrt(x) which is also f(x)=x^(1/2) is simply 1/(2x) or (1/x)*x^(-1).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's all correct except that I'm pretty sure the MSE derivative for y has also a negative sign. like: $-\frac{2}{m}\sum(h(x)-y)$